# enrollment function in c

Tags: c, function, struct

So my task was to make struct which will enter students name,surname,school and class. The problem is that i need to make 2 functions, one will do the enrollment(ask you for the name,surname,school and class) and the other will print everything that u entered. The language is C and i really need help. I am not really good at C so forgive me if i did a stupid mistake.

```
    #include "stdafx.h"

typedef struct uc
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char school[30];
    char clas[30];
}_tStudent;

 struct enrollment(_tStudent T)
{
    printf("Name:");
    scanf("%s",T.name);
    printf("Surname:");
    scanf("%s",T.surname);
    printf("School:");
    scanf("%s",T.school);
    printf("Class:");
    scanf("%s",T.clas);
    return T;
};
void print()
{
    _tStudent uc;
    printf("%s",uc.name);
    printf("%s",uc.surname);
    printf("%s",uc.school);
    printf("%s",uc.clas);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //declarations
    int a;
    int b;
    struct uc iv;
    //work

    printf("Enter new student(0),print every student that u have(1)\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a==0)
    {
        enrollment(iv);
    }
    else
    {
        print;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the language is C (and not C++) then your function declaration is wong:

```
struct enrollment(_tStudent T)
```

should be

```
void enrollment(_tStudent *T)
```

(and you don't need the `return` anymore.)

---

In `main` your declaration should be:

```
struct _tStudent iv;
```

and your call must be:

```
enrollment(&iv);
```

---

Calling a function always requires the `(` and `)`, so `print;` should be `print();` But the print function has a local variable `uc` and you want to print that. But that struct has garbage values. You want to *pas the variable `iv` from `main`*, so:

```
void print(_tStudent *uc)
```

and call:

```
print(&iv);
```

Note that all functions work with *pointers* to the actual struct variable. A pointer is declared with the `*` and to call a function that receives a pointer, you must take the address of the struct you want to pass. You do that with `&`.

In the function you must now *dereference* the pointer. You do that with `->`:

```
scanf("%s",T->name);     // in enrollment()
printf("%s",uc->name);   // in print()
```

Comment: I am sorrry i did not say that i am doing it in visual c++ 2010 so even tho i am doing it in c it is a cpp file so i can do some things from c++

Comment: @PatrikPaunović, either C or C++. They are totally different languages. Even compiling a .cpp file containing pure C, the result will be different from compiling the same file as a .c file. I made the remark because your `struct enrollment(_tStudent T) {` smells like a C++ constructor, which C doesn't have.